# K-Means centroids getting marginalized to having no data points [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

So I have a sort of strange problem. I have a dataset with 240 points and I'm trying to use k-means to cluster it into 100 clusters. I'm using Matlab but I don't have access to the statistics toolbox, so I had to write my own k-means function. It's pretty simple, so that shouldn't be too hard, right? Well, it seems something is wrong with my code:

```
function result=Kmeans(X,c)
[N,n]=size(X);
index=randperm(N);
ctrs = X(index(1:c),:);
old_label = zeros(1,N);
label = ones(1,N);

iter = 0;
while ~isequal(old_label, label)
    old_label = label;
    label = assign_labels(X, ctrs);

    for i = 1:c
        ctrs(i,:) = mean(X(label == i,:));
        if sum(isnan(ctrs(i,:))) ~= 0
            ctrs(i,:) = zeros(1,n);
        end
    end
    iter = iter + 1;
end

result = ctrs;

function label = assign_labels(X, ctrs)
[N,~]=size(X);
[c,~]=size(ctrs);
dist = zeros(N,c);
for i = 1:c
    dist(:,i) = sum((X - repmat(ctrs(i,:),[N,1])).^2,2);
end

[~,label] = min(dist,[],2);
```

It seems what happens is that when I go to recompute the centroids, some centroids have no datapoints assigned to them, so I'm not really sure what to do with that. After doing some research on this, I found that this can happen if you supply arbitrary initial centroids, but in this case the initial centroids are taken from the datapoints themselves, so this doesn't really make sense. I've tried re-assigning these centroids to random datapoints, but that causes the code to not converge (or at least after letting it run all night, the code never converged). Basically they get re-assigned, but that causes other centroids to get marginalized, and repeat. I'm not really sure what's wrong with my code, but I ran this same dataset through R's k-means function for k=100 for 1000 iterations and it managed to converge. Does anyone know what I'm messing up here? Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are making the centre of a cluster all zeroes if any of the dimensions of the cluster centroid are `NaN`.  Do you have a rationale as to why you're doing that?  In any case, I'm going to go through your code and figure out what's wrong.  Kmeans I know very well.

Comment: The NaN only happens if there are no points assigned to the centroid. I wasn't really sure what to do when this happens. I tried randomly picking a datapoint and moving the centroid there, but this ends up causing an infinite loop (the moved centroid causes other centroids to not have any datapoints, and repeat). I just picked assigning the centroid all zeros as a default because I'm not sure what the correct thing to do here would be.

Comment: OK.  The suggestion that I wrote in my post to ensure that all cluster centroids are unique should hopefully fix this problem that you're experiencing.  Try that and see how it goes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through your code one piece at a time and discuss what you're doing with respect to what I know about the `k`-means algorithm.

```
function result=Kmeans(X,c)
[N,n]=size(X);
index=randperm(N);
ctrs = X(index(1:c),:);
old_label = zeros(1,N);
label = ones(1,N);
```

This looks like a function that takes in a data matrix of size `N x n`, where `N` is the number of points you have in your dataset, while `n` is the dimension of a point in your dataset.  This function also takes in `c`: the desired number of output clusters.`index` provides a random permutation between `1` to as many data points as you have, and then we select at random `c` points from this permutation which you have used to initialize your cluster centres.

---

```
iter = 0;
while ~isequal(old_label, label)
    old_label = label;
    label = assign_labels(X, ctrs);

    for i = 1:c
        ctrs(i,:) = mean(X(label == i,:));
        if sum(isnan(ctrs(i,:))) ~= 0
            ctrs(i,:) = zeros(1,n);
        end
    end
    iter = iter + 1;
end

result = ctrs;
```

For `k`-means, we basically keep iterating until the cluster membership of each point from the previous iteration matches with the current iteration, which is what you have going with your `while` loop.  Now, `label` determines the cluster membership of each point in your dataset.  Now, for each cluster that exists, you determine what the mean data point is, then assign this mean data point as the new cluster centre for each cluster.  For some reason, should you experience any `NaN` for any dimension of your cluster centre, you set your new cluster centre to all zeroes instead.  <s>This looks very abnormal to me, and I'll provide a suggestion later.</s>  **Edit:**  Now I understand why you did this.  This is because should you have any clusters that are empty, you would simply make this cluster centre all zeroes as you wouldn't be able to find the mean of empty clusters.  This can be solved with my suggestion for duplicate initial clusters towards the end of this post.

---

```
function label = assign_labels(X, ctrs)
[N,~]=size(X);
[c,~]=size(ctrs);
dist = zeros(N,c);
for i = 1:c
    dist(:,i) = sum((X - repmat(ctrs(i,:),[N,1])).^2,2);
end

[~,label] = min(dist,[],2);
```

This function takes in a dataset `X` and the current cluster centres for this iteration, and it should return a label list of where each point belongs to each cluster.  This also looks correct because for each column of `dist`, you are calculating the distance between each point to each cluster, where those distances are in the i<sup>th</sup> column for the i<sup>th</sup> cluster.  One optimization trick that I would use is to avoid using `repmat` here and use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) which handles the replication internally.  Therefore, do this instead:

```
function label = assign_labels(X, ctrs)
[N,~]=size(X);
[c,~]=size(ctrs);
dist = zeros(N,c);
for i = 1:c
    dist(:,i) = sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, ctrs(i,:)).^2, 2);
end

[~,label] = min(dist,[],2);
```

---

Now, this all looks correct.  I also ran some tests myself and it all seems to work out, provided that the **initial cluster centres are unique**.  One small problem with `k`-means is that we implicitly assume that all cluster centres are **unique**.  Should they not be unique, then you'll run into a problem where two clusters (or more) have the exact same initial cluster centres.... so which cluster should the data point be assigned to?  When you're doing the `min` in your `assign_labels` function, should you have two identical cluster centres, the cluster label that the point gets assigned to will be the minimum of these two numbers.  This is why you will have a cluster with no points in it, as all of the points that should have been assigned to this cluster get assigned to the other.

As such, you may have two (or more) initial cluster centres that are **the same** upon randomization.  Even though the permutation of the indices to select are unique, the actual **data points** themselves may **not** be unique upon selection.  One thing that I can impose is to loop over the permutation **until** you get a unique set of initial clusters without repeats.  As such, try doing this at the beginning of your code instead.

```
[N,n]=size(X);
index=randperm(N);
ctrs = X(index(1:c),:);

while size(unique(ctrs, 'rows'), 1) ~= c
    index=randperm(N);
    ctrs = X(index(1:c),:);
end

old_label = zeros(1,N);
label = ones(1,N);

iter = 0;

%// While loop appears here
```

This will ensure that you have a unique set of initial clusters before you continue on in your code.  Now, going back to your `NaN` stuff inside the `for` loop.  <s>I honestly don't see how any dimension could result in `NaN` after you compute the mean if your data doesn't have any `NaN` to begin with.  I would suggest you get rid of this in your code as (to me) it doesn't look very useful.</s>  **Edit:**  You can now remove the `NaN` check as the initial cluster centres should now be unique.

---

This should hopefully fix your problems you're experiencing.  Good luck!

Comment: YES! Thank you! This was exactly it. Apparently my data had a few identical datapoints and when I added in that check you recommended, it fixed everything. For good measure I also added an assert statement immediately before this so that in the case that there are not `c` unique datapoints overall, the code doesn't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Rae_III - AHA.  There we go lol.  It sounded like there were duplicate data points in your matrix, so that's one thing I use before you even run the algorithm.  I've experienced the same anomaly before.  I've also edited my post to explain why you need the `NaN` check there for future readers.  Glad I could help, and good job on the `assert` statement!

Answer (score 0):

"Losing" a cluster is not half as special as one may think, due to the nature of k-means.

Consider duplicates. Lets assume that all your first k points are identical, what would happen in your code? There is a reason you need to carefully handle this case. The simplest solution would be to leave the centroid as it was before, and live with degenerate clusters.

Given that you only have 240 points, but want to use k=100, don't expect too good results. Most objects will be on their own... choosing a much too large k is probably a reason why you do see this degeneration effect a lot. Let's assume out of these 240, fewer than 100 are unique... Then you cannot have 100 non-empty clusters... Plus, I would consider this kind of result "overfitting", anyway.

If you don't have the toolboxes you need in Matlab, maybe you should move on to free software. Octave, R, Weka, ELKI, ... there is plenty of software, some of which is much more powerful when it comes to clustering than pure Matlab (in particular, if you don't have the toolboxes).

Also *benchmark*. You will be surprised of the performance differences.